# Software Removal Via Batch/Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am attempting to remove [Lenovo Fingerprint Manager Pro](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/len-15999) from a dozen or so Windows 8.1 machines due to the recurring vulnerabilities of the software.

I wrote the following batch file in order to remove it. While it worked on my initial test, it has failed upon subsequent attempts.

I was looking to see where the error is, and if someone may have a better way about going about this?

```bat
@echo off
REM This file will remove the Lenovo Finger print scanner and the relevant registry entries.
DEL "C:\windows\Installer\fa4f.msi"
set folder="C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Fingerprint Manager Pro"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
cd /d %folder%
cd ..
rmdir %folder%
REG DELETE HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{940B1CC9-013F-468e-BBBF-4A975461F120} /f
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Lenovo\Fingerprint Software /f
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{314FAD12-F785-4471-BCE8-AB506642B9A1} /f
ECHO Lenovo Fingerprint Scanner Removed Successfully.
```

Comment: Removing a registry entry does not uninstall the software, you should run it's uninstall routine before doing all of those 'clean-up' actions.

Comment: That's a messy uninstall, deleting the program files folder and _some_ registry keys is going to leave parts of the program behind. You'd be better off finding the [UninstallString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx) and using it (with appropriate silent/unattended flags) to uninstall the program properly.

Comment: Agreed, registered and shared/common files, services and possibly devices etc. can also be part of its install. Because you already know its Uninstall registry key, you can easily grab the UninstallString from that key, and execute it, prior to everything else in that script.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me enough of what I needed.

Comment: Please either post the solution as an answer or delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell you can get the program as an object and call uninstall on that object:

```
$App = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
     $_.Name -match "Software Name"}
$App.uninstall()
```

The if you really want to cleanup registry and all that fun stuff you can do that afterwards.